# How to route Dynamic Controller/Action Pattern in MVC 4 -Routing for ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I hope it is a better way to write the route in MVC 4 and would like some feedback.

Could you let me know if the routing patterns below are the best way to do it in MVC 4?

I have an application that has a requirement to show the url in the following format.

http://domain.com/777-777-7777-777-7777/Page1

http://domain.com/777-777-7777-777-7777/Page2

The 777-777-7777-777-7777 is an account number.  PageX is the report page number.

I am trying to avoid trashing other controller routes in my project.
Below is what I tried but need feedback if this will trash future controllers.

**Report Number plus page route**

```
routes.MapRoute( 
"Report", // Route name 
"{AccountNumber}/{ReportPage}",  
new { controller = "Report", action = "Navigate", AccountNumber =     UrlParameter.Optional, ReportPage = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

**Future Controller I don't want to trash.**

```
routes.MapRoute( 
"FutureController", // Route name 
"FutureController/{action}/{id}",  
new { controller = "FutureController",id= UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ur routes are OK. Its not gonna break with current setup. Only thing to remember when writing routes is that you put more specific routes first because they are processed in order and first matching route is picked by url engine. I must however say that your `ReportPage` parameter would contains values like `page1` and `page1` instead of numeric 1 or 2. I have seen someone writing rules where only the numeric portion would be received in action result. As far as I can remember it was something like

```
routes.MapRoute( 
"Report", // Route name 
"{AccountNumber}/page{ReportPage}",  
new { controller = "Report", action = "Navigate", AccountNumber =     UrlParameter.Optional, ReportPage = UrlParameter.Optional},new{ReportPage = "\d+"});
```

This way you will have urls like `http://domain.com/account/page1` but in action methods you will receive the numeric values for `ReportPage` parameter. It would, however, not match when page number is absent. For this scenario you can add another route like the guy recommended in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582821/paging-and-routing-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, Do you know if MVC 4 has any better ways to write this?

Comment: ur routes r ok. jusr remember the rule: put more specific urls first