# How To do Routing For Pagination in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pagination, routes

I am doing pagination for an application in ASP.NET MVC 5 and stuck on the routing for the paging. Following is the format I am trying to use:

```
<a href="~/Home/page/1)">Next</a>
```

Right now, it works well with the following:

```
<a href="~/Home?page=1">Next</a>
```

In the RouteConfig file, I've set the following routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute( //Route For The Pagination
            "Home",
            "Home/page/{page}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute( //Default Route
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        MainDbContext db = new MainDbContext();

        var listItems = new List<List>();

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            listItems = (db.Lists.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            listItems = (db.Lists.Where(m => m.Public == "Yes").ToList());
        }

        var pager = new Pager(listItems.Count(), page);

        var viewModel = new List
        {
            Items = listItems.Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            Pager = pager
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. But right now, when I run the application, for the paging section, it shows this message '**Server Error in '/' Application - The resource cannot be found**'. Do I need to configure anything else and would expect suggestions from the experts. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the controller that processes the paging route?

Comment: I've edited the post. I hope, you asked about the above controller that deals with paging. Let me know if I've missed anything as I am totally new to ASP.NET MVC. Thanks.

Comment: I assume the `)` in `<a href="~/Home/page/1)">Next</a>` is a typo? Otherwise the code you have shown will work fine. Are those the only routes, and are they in the order you have shown?

Comment: Yes. They are in the order as shown. Basically I am doing the paging with razor in the front-end like this: @Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", "Home", new { page = (Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1) }, null) or even tried this one: <a href="~/Home/page/@Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1)">Next</a>. I am little bit confused about it. Is there anything more to configure in the back-end? I would expect your suggestion in this regard and tried the solution provided below. But did not work. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582821/paging-and-routing-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

In order for the route rule for paging to work, you need to define a different action.

For example:

```
routes.MapRoute( //Route For The Pagination
    "Home",
    "Home/page/{page}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "PagedIndex" }
    );
```

Then, you implement inside `HomeController` the `PagedIndex` action.

```
public ActionResult PagedIndex(int? page)
{
    // code here to build your model
    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

You also need to change `return View(viewModel);` to `return View("Index", viewModel);`. Otherwise, it will try to run the `PagedIndex` view.

**Edit**: Adding the entire files:

**App_Start/RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute( //Route For The Pagination
            "Home",
            "Home/page/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "PagedIndex" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.Home.Index model = new Models.Home.Index();

        return View("Index", model);
    }

    public ActionResult PagedIndex(int? page)
    {
        Models.Home.Index model = new Models.Home.Index();
        model.page = page ?? 0;

        return View("Index", model);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Models/Index.cs**

```
// You won't need this, it is just a mock model I created to test the code
namespace SOQuestion.Models.Home
{
    public class Index
    {
        public int page { get; set; }

        public Index()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model SOQuestion.Models.Home.Index

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>This is the <b>Index</b> view</h2>
        <p>
            Current index is: <b>@Model.page</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            @if (Model.page > 0)
            {
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="/Home/Page/@(Model.page - 1)">Previous</a>
            }

            <a class="btn btn-info" href="/Home/Page/@(Model.page + 1)">Next</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried but did not work. I am using the HomeController and implemented what you suggested in the same controller.

Comment: Did you change the routing rule as well (e.g. `action = "PagedIndex"` instead of `action = "Index"`)?

Comment: Yes and created the action. Is there any other way to get this format: <a href="~/Home/page/1)">Next</a> I mean in the controller? By the way, why do we need another action to do so?

Comment: Mmmm... thing is I tried this code before posting, and it worked. Is the route rule for pagination before the default rule?

Comment: Yes. It is. See I am using this in the view:  <a href="~/Home/page/@(Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1)">Next</a>. So does it create any conflict? Whenever I run the project, it shows up: 'Server Error in '/' Application - The resource cannot be found'.

Comment: I don't see how this would cause the issue. The message indicates that it is a routing issue, the code inside the view never gets to execute. In the PagedIndex action you have this? `return View("Index", viewModel);` If not, it could explain the error.

Comment: Yes. I did and am trying it again. Could you share the HomeController codes again? Then I may understand what I missed.

Comment: Posted the code, also you can download the code from here and try it out. http://codingstill.com/demos/SOQuestion.rar